# How can i set my c# program as default-browser which accepts http/https links?

Tags: c#, browser, hyperlink, handle, default-browser

I want my program to listen for links, which were send by other applications as default browser.

I tried out some searchings but i only found this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/shell/default-programs#becoming-the-default-browser

and i also cannot find an example, which shows up a way to solve this.

I hope for answers and would like to say "Thank you" to all answers.

Greetings

Penc

Answer (score 0):

Originally it was just possible for your programm to set any file or protcoll asocaition. What happens was the predictable: Every other programmer abused that.

So it had to be take away and moved into the [Default Programms UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/shell/default-programs#default-programs-ui). Now you can only tell windows your programms is avalible for that format.

But you can not become the default anymore without user action or maybe some Admin Level Operations/Registery editing. Maybe there is a odd allowances (for the common Browsers for example), but those will be on a case by case basis.